# identifier error onclick of image

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, onclick

Here is my code: Onclick of delte icon, I am passing values

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i]["actions"] = '<div>' + '<span class="delete" onclick="getServerId('+ data[i].id.toString()+','+ data[i].region_code+');" ></span>' +'</div>';                                          
    }
```

I am passing id and the region code on delete. This is how my onclick looks

```
<span onclick="getServerId(server-0a95755c-369b-4518-8b86-68864d94be21);" class="delete"></span>
```

But it gives me an error saying :

```
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal


getServerId(server-0a95755c-369b-4518-8b86-68864d94be21);
--------------------------
```

Can someone please help me out? Thanks

Comment: You are passing a reference, not a string. Change the code in `onclick="getServerId(\"'+ data[i].id.toString()+','+ data[i].region_code+'\");`

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried the same.
     `code for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i]["actions"] = '<div>' + '<span class="delete" onclick="getServerId(\"'+ data[i].id.toString()+','+ data[i].region_code+'\");" ></span>' +'</div>';
        } `


but when I hovered the mouse using firebug it gave me this:

`code <span class="delete" server-0a95755c-369b-4518-8b86-68864d94be21,dfw");"="" onclick="getServerId("></span> `

Please help me out